# Suppress Ruby Interpreter Printing Source Code in Eclipse Console on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, eclipse, macos

I'm using Eclipse on both Windows and Mac OS X. I installed the Ruby development tools (for Eclipse) in both installations, and have `Ruby 2.0.0p247` installed on **both** systems. I am using the default interpreter `irb` on both installations as well.

However, the is one major difference between me using the two systems:

1. On my Windows installation, the interpreter does not print the script source (Class) and method execution (just the `puts` lines I have in the script).
2. On my Mac OS X installation, the interpreter *does* print the entire script source and method execution, *as well as* all my `puts` statements.

**NOTE**: I just tested this, and if run through `irb` directly (not through Eclipse console), with `ruby mySource.rb`, it does not print the source code and method execution. I have *not* tested this on Windows because Windows does not have this problem in the first place, so it seems to be a configuration in Eclipse for Mac OSX, but the weird thing is that I haven't made any console configuration changes in Eclipse on either system.

I suppose the only difference between the two installations is that I used [`RVM`](https://rvm.io/) to install on Mac OS X, and [`Ruby Installer`](http://rubyinstaller.org/), but I really don't see how that would make a difference in console output in Eclipse when Eclipse has the same interpreter. The current versions used by both OS are the same (`ruby -v`).

**EDIT**: Example running both through Eclipse and through Terminal on Mac OS X:

[image]

**How can the printing of source code and function calls be suppressed?**

Comment: Are you asking how to suppress the printing of the source code on OSX Eclipse?

Comment: Essentially, yes. If this is the default behavior in Eclipse OS X, then I would like to supress it. Imo it's a bunch of noise to see the same source code in 2 separate sub-windows in Eclipse (console and open .rb file).